# Simple random walk on a finite network

Tags: random-walk

We have a simple random walk S on a finite set of $\mathbb{N}: {0,...,N}$.

Let $m_x$ be the expected number of steps, starting at
$x$, required to reach $0$ or $N$ for the first time. Show that $m_x$ satisfies the conditions:

(a) $m_0 = 0$

(b) $m_N = 0$

(c) $m_x = \frac{1}{2}m_{x-1}+\frac{1}{2}m_{x+1}+1$.

For (a) and (b) my reasoning goes as follows. Substitute either $0$ or $N$ for $x$ in $m_x$. Then we are looking for the expected numbers of steps before reaching either $0$ or $N$ starting in either $0$ or $N$. This is $0$ since we are already there.

How do we show that the difference equation applies though?

Comment: See "help" above to discover what sort of questions to ask here.

Comment: The difference equation follows from the total expectation formula and the Markov property of the random walk.

Comment: Do you mean the total expectation of the stopping time? We have that $m_x = \mathbb{E}_x(\tau_{0,N})$ with $\tau_{0,N}$ the minimum of the number of steps it takes to reach either $0$ or $N$ from the starting point $x$. I can't seem to figure out how to calculate this expectation.